# How to inject object id into success url

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am building an object with a `CreateView` and some `UpdateView`. I came across a pattern that I think may be optimised:

```
class TitleSection(CreateView):
    # conf

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('project-creation:step2', kwargs={'pk': self.object.id})


class AmountSection(UpdateView):
    # conf

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('project-creation:step3', kwargs={'pk': self.object.id})


class DescriptionSection(UpdateView):
    # config

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('other:url', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})
```

As you can see I redirect with reverse_lazy with injecting the current `self.object.id` each time.

Do you know if there is a way to optimise this?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do micro-optimization, you'd be better off looking at other bottlenecks in your code, these single lines of code aren't going to be causing you any real problems

Comment: I know, it just seems that something could be done here.

Comment: Note that you can use `reverse` instead of `reverse_lazy` because the call is inside the method. Apart from that, the code looks fine.